# A lower bound on $e^z $ using the reverse triangle inequality

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, exponential-function

For $z \in \mathbb{C}$ I have come up with the following lower bound:
$$
|e^{z}| \geq 2 - e^{|z|}
$$

I wanted to get some clarification **if** the above is true.

My proof uses the reverse triangle inequality for complex numbers $|x-y| \geq |x|-|y|$. For $\{ a_{j} \}_{j=0}^{N} \subset \mathbb{C}$, we have:
$$
|a_{0} + a_{1}| = | a_{0} - ( - a_{1} ) | \geq | a_{0}| - |a_{1}| \\
\ 
|a_{0} + a_{1} + a_{2}| = | a_{0} + a_{1} - (- a_2 ) | \geq | a_{0} + a_{1} | - |a_{2}| \geq | a_{0} | - | a_{1} | - |a_{2}|
$$

I *think* this generalizes to $\left| \sum_{j=1}^{N} a_{j} \right| \geq a_{0} - \sum_{j=1}^{N} | a_{j} |$. If this is true, then this means that:
$$
\left| e^{z} \right| = \left| \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n!} \right| \geq 1 - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{| z | ^n}{n!} = 2 - e^{|z|}
$$

Does this look feasible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You approach is fine, but $e^{\text{Re}(z)}+e^{|z|}\geq 2$ is trivial both for $|z|\geq\log 2$ and for $\text{Re}(z)\geq 0$, and the AM-GM inequality $e^{\text{Re}(z)}+e^{|z|} \geq 2\exp\left(\frac{\text{Re}(z)+|z|}{2}\right)\geq 2\exp(0) $ makes it trivial also for $\text{Re}(z)\leq 0, |z|\leq\log 2$.